# Source function in R, error cannot find file - do I have to change working directory?

Tags: r

This may be a duplicate, but I couldn't find a solution when I searched online and it's an issue that has been bugging me for some time. I am given a zip file with 2 .R files, I download the zip and move the .R files into a directory on my computer, let's say "/Users/Home/StatisticsStuff/LearningR/".

My two files are Stats1.R and Stats2.R, and the first line of code in Stats1.R is:

```
source(Stats2.R)
```

and I get the following error message:

```
> source("Stats2.R")
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : cannot open file 'Stats2.R': No such file or directory
```

when i run getwd(), to see which working directory I'm in, I get:

```
getwd()
"/Users/Home"
```

It seems like it would be a pain to have to change working directories in order to source files? Is there something I'm doing wrong here with regards to what I'm expecting from the source() function? Do I have to put a line in my code above everything else using setwd("whatever the correct wd is").

Any thoughts appreciated!

Comment: yes!! either use `setwd()` or while sourcing itself have the entire path

Comment: Just add the path to the source file. You can either use absolute or relative paths depending on your situation. Something like `source("/Users/Home/StatisticsStuff/LearningR/Stats2.R")` should work.

Comment: okay thanks. I guess I was hoping that R and the source function automatically searched my directories for a file with a matching name, that way I didn't automatically have to setwd() on top of each file that I source from.

Comment: Suggesting to use the [`here`](https://github.com/krlmlr/here) package in combination with an RProject to simplify your working directory issues.

Comment: package ‘here’ is not available (for R version 3.3.0) 

I'm okay with setwd or putting the full path in source(), just a mild inconvenience. thanks

Comment: It is currently only available on Github. Install it with `devtools::install_github("krlmlr/here")`. And read the docs to understand what it is doing :)

Answer (score 3):

I added this before sourcing, it worked for me :

```
setwd(dirname(getwd()))
```

Answer (score 1):

first write this command list.files() then you can know which location of your R is pointing or see the below image that R-Pointing to then write the source command with correct path. it will be executed.

follow these steps to see the R pointing path.

1. Go to properties of your R software which is installed as below
2. Find the Start in path: which is the path R pointing to so in source command use that path